# Launch jquery facebox from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

I use this inside a function,

```
document.getElementById("DeleteConfirmationdiv").style.display = 'block';
```

now I want to launch this `DeleteConfirmationdiv` using the [jQuery Facebox](http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/) plugin. Is it possible?

Thus far I've been using facebox like this,

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $.facebox.settings.opacity = 0.2;
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
});
```

and my page has this,

```
<a id="signin" href="#signindiv" rel="facebox">
   <img alt="" src="Css/images/Sign in.png" height="19" width="59" />
</a>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work,

```
function showDisplaydiv() {
    $.facebox.settings.opacity = 0.2;
    $('#ConfirmationPanel').facebox();
    //document.getElementById("ConfirmationPanel").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("datatable").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("ImageButtonDiv").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("adddiv").style.display = 'none';
    return false;
}
```

i call this function from a button,

```
 <asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" CssClass="deletebuttons" 
 OnClientClick="javascript:return(Deleteyuitable()&&showDisplaydiv(''));"
onfocus="this.blur();" Text="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve got it to work,

```
$(function(){
    $.facebox({ div: '#box' });
});
```

Just did this,

```
function showDisplaydiv() {
    $.facebox.settings.opacity = 0.2;
    $.facebox({ div: '#ConfirmationPanel' });
    //document.getElementById("ConfirmationPanel").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("datatable").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("ImageButtonDiv").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("adddiv").style.display = 'none';
    return false;
}
```